# C# Cannot Connect To WCF Service When Called From COM Interop

Tags: c#, app-config, com-interop

I have a C# class library that works fine when called from a C# application. However, it also supports COM Interop so that older C++ clients can also call it. The C# Class library has a WCF service reference in it. The WCF call works fine from a C# call but when called from COM Interop, I get an error stating:

```
"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'xxxx' in the ServiceModel client configuration section....."
```

The reference is in the app.config or more specifically the .config which gets built when you build the DLL. It seems that when called from a C# application, the DLL knows where to look for this config file (i.e. the same directory as the dll) and hence finds the needed info. However, when called from COM Interop, it seems it must be looking somewhere else for it and not finding it.

Does anyone know how I fix this and make it work in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a .config file in a COM server is quite unpractical.  The one that System.Configuration looks for is *not* associated with the DLL but with the EXE.  Is name is `foo.exe.config` where "foo" is the name of the EXE and must be stored in the same directory as the .exe.  A COM server can't predict what EXE is going to load it.

But you can make it work by hand by storing the .config file with the right name in the right directory.

Comment: Yes this just occurred to me and I was coming back to answer my own question. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET it is always the executable that has a configuration file, not the .dlls it uses. Even if it is the .dll that needs configuration information, it has to be included in the config file of the application.

By default, the CLR will look for a config file called .config in the same directory as the exe. If this happens to be an old C++ program makes no difference, at least according to my experience. You can just copy the config file to the directory of the C++ program, rename it to match the executable and you're good to go.

If you want a solution that just works everywhere, consider expressing the configuration in code, possibly after manually loading the needed configuration information from some source.